# How to run a for loop in r with two conditions from vectors

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, conditional-statements

I have the following data frame (see `dput()` below):

```
                   Date     Time   Price Volume  VolumeSEK Bid.Price Ask.Price BidAskSpread MidPrice    Company
1005   11.09.2018 25204.72  98.500   1153 113570.500     98.58     98.58         0.00   98.580        SEB
1071   11.09.2018 25209.89 233.300    158  36861.400    233.30    233.80         0.50  233.550 Alfa Laval
88995  12.09.2018 25220.83 170.500    101  17220.500    170.50    170.60         0.10  170.550    Skanska
1115   11.09.2018 25224.86 233.300      1    233.300    233.30    233.70         0.40  233.500 Alfa Laval
89001  12.09.2018 25229.77  96.960    937  90851.520     96.96     97.04         0.08   97.000        SEB
259224 14.09.2018 25239.65 213.950    126  26957.700    214.00    214.20         0.20  214.100   Swedbank
329555 17.09.2018 25244.28 178.375     19   3389.125    178.35    178.60         0.25  178.475    Skanska
1177   11.09.2018 25248.27 233.400    127  29641.800    233.30    233.60         0.30  233.450 Alfa Laval
1197   11.09.2018 25256.45 286.600    267  76522.200    286.60    287.10         0.50  286.850   Kinnevik
1200   11.09.2018 25258.17  98.520     32   3152.640     98.30     98.38         0.08   98.340        SEB
```

and two vectors

```
Comp<- c("Skanska", "SEB", "Swedbank", "Kinnevik", "Investor", "Alfa Laval")
Day<- c("11.09.2018","12.09.2018", "13.09.2018", "14.09.2018", "15.09.2018", "16.09.2018", "17.09.2018")
```

I would like to compute the mean VolumeSEK for every single stock for every single day and save the results in a matrix. I am quite new to R so my first guess was to use a for loop. However, this did not work for me so far. This was my approach, but I am a little lost and this might not be the right approach at all.

```
    mat <- matrix(, nrow = 6, ncol = 7))
for (i in 1:Comp){
  for(j in 1:Day){
    mat[i,j]= mean(df$VolumeSEK[df$Company==Comp[i]& df$Date==Day[j]])
  }#2
}#1
```

Any feedback and hints are highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
df<-structure(list(X.RIC = structure(c(8L, 2L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 12L, 
    10L, 2L, 6L, 8L, 12L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 8L, 12L, 4L, 6L, 
    8L, 12L, 12L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 12L, 4L, 12L, 12L, 4L, 12L, 4L, 4L, 
    8L, 6L, 12L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 12L, 12L, 8L, 4L, 6L, 
    8L), .Label = c("ALFA.ST", "ALFAs.BCO", "INVEb.ST", "INVEBs.BCO", 
    "KINVb.ST", "KINVBs.BCO", "SEBa.ST", "SEBAs.BCO", "SKAb.ST", 
    "SKABs.BCO", "SWEDa.ST", "SWEDAs.BCO"), class = "factor"), Date = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 
    1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
    5L), .Label = c("11.09.2018", "12.09.2018", "13.09.2018", "14.09.2018", 
    "17.09.2018"), class = "factor"), Time = c(25204.724866253, 25209.891063318, 
    25220.83, 25224.862743496, 25229.77, 25239.65, 25244.28, 25248.266841503, 
    25256.450392157, 25258.169598025, 25259.431887444, 25265.42, 
    25267.73, 25282.608168894, 25297.72, 25300.78, 25304.39, 25312.181336031, 
    25314.992406965, 25334.129581998, 25337.19, 25337.52, 25338.977745285, 
    25339.14, 25340.48, 25341.34500136, 25346.804459672, 25347.23, 
    25351.80572164, 25352.089646376, 25354.56, 25356.805147054, 25359.55, 
    25361.804327741, 25366.804555871, 25370.11, 25372.53, 25378.384314178, 
    25378.884337058, 25386.788916974, 25388.64, 25389.67, 25392.033315652, 
    25401.17, 25403.9, 25421.773090991, 25421.98, 25424.19, 25424.21, 
    25424.85), Type = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Quote", 
    "Trade"), class = "factor"), Price = c(98.5, 233.3, 170.5, 233.3, 
    96.96, 213.95, 178.375, 233.4, 286.6, 98.52, 213.1, 409.75, 290.9, 
    98.42, 291.5, 235, 288.8, 98.4, 213.2, 407.8, 291.3, 96.78, 213, 
    212.3, 406.48, 407.9, 407.9, 212.8, 407.9, 213, 212.8, 407.9, 
    212.8, 407.9, 407.9, 96.86, 288.5, 213, 407.7, 407.9, 291.3, 
    178.7, 407.8, 170.9, 213.9, 212.9, 96.46, 409.7, 288.3, 96.88
    ), Volume = c(1153L, 158L, 101L, 1L, 937L, 126L, 19L, 127L, 267L, 
    32L, 64L, 17L, 31L, 733L, 100L, 130L, 51L, 46L, 214L, 21L, 78L, 
    155L, 55L, 761L, 295L, 121L, 6L, 113L, 5L, 350L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 
    6L, 5L, 711L, 567L, 350L, 13L, 8L, 4L, 110L, 587L, 607L, 1272L, 
    363L, 13L, 419L, 63L, 21L), Venue = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "SINT[GV5_TEXT]", class = "factor"), 
        VolumeSEK = c(113570.5, 36861.4, 17220.5, 233.3, 90851.52, 
        26957.7, 3389.125, 29641.8, 76522.2, 3152.64, 13638.4, 6965.75, 
        9017.9, 72141.86, 29150, 30550, 14728.8, 4526.4, 45624.8, 
        8563.8, 22721.4, 15000.9, 11715, 161560.3, 119911.6, 49355.9, 
        2447.4, 24046.4, 2039.5, 74550, 851.2, 2039.5, 638.4, 2447.4, 
        2039.5, 68867.46, 163579.5, 74550, 5300.1, 3263.2, 1165.2, 
        19657, 239378.6, 103736.3, 272080.8, 77282.7, 1253.98, 171664.3, 
        18162.9, 2034.48), Bid.Price = c(98.58, 233.3, 170.5, 233.3, 
        96.96, 214, 178.35, 233.3, 286.6, 98.3, 212.8, 409.6, 290.9, 
        98.38, 291.5, 235, 288.6, 98.38, 213.1, 407.5, 291.3, 96.76, 
        213, 212.1, 406.2, 407.5, 407.5, 212.8, 407.5, 213, 212.8, 
        407.5, 212.8, 407.5, 407.5, 96.88, 288.5, 213.1, 407.3, 407.6, 
        291.6, 178.6, 407.5, 170.75, 213.8, 213, 96.46, 409.3, 288.2, 
        96.88), Ask.Price = c(98.58, 233.8, 170.6, 233.7, 97.04, 
        214.2, 178.6, 233.6, 287.1, 98.38, 213, 410, 291.1, 98.42, 
        291.7, 235.4, 289, 98.46, 213.3, 407.8, 291.5, 96.78, 213.2, 
        212.4, 406.5, 407.9, 407.9, 213.1, 407.9, 213.1, 213.1, 407.9, 
        213.1, 407.9, 407.9, 96.98, 288.8, 213.2, 407.8, 407.9, 291.9, 
        178.75, 407.8, 170.95, 213.9, 213.1, 96.54, 409.6, 288.6, 
        96.96), BidAskSpread = c(0, 0.5, 0.1, 0.399999999999977, 
        0.08, 0.2, 0.25, 0.299999999999983, 0.5, 0.0799999999999983, 
        0.199999999999989, 0.4, 0.2, 0.0400000000000063, 0.2, 0.4, 
        0.4, 0.0799999999999983, 0.200000000000017, 0.300000000000011, 
        0.2, 0.02, 0.199999999999989, 0.3, 0.3, 0.399999999999977, 
        0.399999999999977, 0.3, 0.399999999999977, 0.0999999999999943, 
        0.3, 0.399999999999977, 0.3, 0.399999999999977, 0.399999999999977, 
        0.1, 0.3, 0.0999999999999943, 0.5, 0.299999999999955, 0.3, 
        0.15, 0.300000000000011, 0.2, 0.1, 0.0999999999999943, 0.08, 
        0.3, 0.4, 0.08), MidPrice = c(98.58, 233.55, 170.55, 233.5, 
        97, 214.1, 178.475, 233.45, 286.85, 98.34, 212.9, 409.8, 
        291, 98.4, 291.6, 235.2, 288.8, 98.42, 213.2, 407.65, 291.4, 
        96.77, 213.1, 212.25, 406.35, 407.7, 407.7, 212.95, 407.7, 
        213.05, 212.95, 407.7, 212.95, 407.7, 407.7, 96.93, 288.65, 
        213.15, 407.55, 407.75, 291.75, 178.675, 407.65, 170.85, 
        213.85, 213.05, 96.5, 409.45, 288.4, 96.92), Company = structure(c(4L, 
        1L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 
        3L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 
        2L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
        4L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("Alfa Laval", "Investor", "Kinnevik", 
        "SEB", "Skanska", "Swedbank"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("X.RIC", 
    "Date", "Time", "Type", "Price", "Volume", "Venue", "VolumeSEK", 
    "Bid.Price", "Ask.Price", "BidAskSpread", "MidPrice", "Company"
    ), row.names = c(1005L, 1071L, 88995L, 1115L, 89001L, 259224L, 
    329555L, 1177L, 1197L, 1200L, 1201L, 259266L, 89158L, 1253L, 
    178546L, 89199L, 329638L, 1312L, 1319L, 1369L, 259339L, 89245L, 
    1383L, 178643L, 89249L, 1385L, 1388L, 329712L, 1401L, 1404L, 
    329722L, 1412L, 329729L, 1418L, 1421L, 329762L, 329771L, 1437L, 
    1443L, 1471L, 259393L, 329810L, 1485L, 89373L, 259439L, 1532L, 
    178820L, 259511L, 329870L, 329871L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

data.table approach, casted to wide format

```
library(data.table)
dcast( setDT(df)[ Company %in% Comp & Date %in% Day, ][, list( mean = mean(VolumeSEK)), by = .(Company, Date)], Company ~ Date )

#       Company 11.09.2018 12.09.2018 13.09.2018 14.09.2018 17.09.2018
# 1: Alfa Laval   22245.50   30550.00         NA         NA         NA
# 2:   Investor   31687.49  119911.60         NA   89315.02         NA
# 3:   Kinnevik   76522.20    9017.90   29150.00   11943.30   65490.40
# 4:        SEB   48347.85   52926.21    1253.98         NA   35450.97
# 5:    Skanska         NA   60478.40         NA         NA   11523.06
# 6:   Swedbank   49560.15         NA  161560.30  149519.25    8512.00
```

switch `Company ~ Date` to `Date ~ Company` for casting the other way around (i.e. Companies to columns).

Answer (score 1):

Using basic R:

```
aggregate(VolumeSEK ~ Date + Company, data=df, FUN = mean)

         Date    Company VolumeSEK
1  11.09.2018 Alfa Laval  22245.50
2  12.09.2018 Alfa Laval  30550.00
3  11.09.2018   Investor  31687.49
4  12.09.2018   Investor 119911.60
5  14.09.2018   Investor  89315.02
6  11.09.2018   Kinnevik  76522.20
7  12.09.2018   Kinnevik   9017.90
8  13.09.2018   Kinnevik  29150.00
9  14.09.2018   Kinnevik  11943.30
10 17.09.2018   Kinnevik  65490.40
11 11.09.2018        SEB  48347.85
12 12.09.2018        SEB  52926.21
13 13.09.2018        SEB   1253.98
14 17.09.2018        SEB  35450.97
15 12.09.2018    Skanska  60478.40
16 17.09.2018    Skanska  11523.06
17 11.09.2018   Swedbank  49560.15
18 13.09.2018   Swedbank 161560.30
19 14.09.2018   Swedbank 149519.25
20 17.09.2018   Swedbank   8512.00
```

This calculates the mean of VolumeSEK for each Company and Date pair. This is in a long format but if you need it as wide do:

```
reshape(df2, idvar = "Company", timevar = "Date", direction = "wide")

      Company VolumeSEK.11.09.2018 VolumeSEK.12.09.2018 VolumeSEK.14.09.2018 VolumeSEK.13.09.2018 VolumeSEK.17.09.2018
1  Alfa Laval             22245.50             30550.00                   NA                   NA                   NA
3    Investor             31687.49            119911.60             89315.02                   NA                   NA
6    Kinnevik             76522.20              9017.90             11943.30             29150.00             65490.40
11        SEB             48347.85             52926.21                   NA              1253.98             35450.97
15    Skanska                   NA             60478.40                   NA                   NA             11523.06
17   Swedbank             49560.15                   NA            149519.25            161560.30              8512.00
```

where `df2` is the result from aggregate above.

For this last step you can also use the `reshape2` library and do:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df2, Company ~ Date, value.var = "VolumeSEK")

     Company 11.09.2018 12.09.2018 13.09.2018 14.09.2018 17.09.2018
1 Alfa Laval   22245.50   30550.00         NA         NA         NA
2   Investor   31687.49  119911.60         NA   89315.02         NA
3   Kinnevik   76522.20    9017.90   29150.00   11943.30   65490.40
4        SEB   48347.85   52926.21    1253.98         NA   35450.97
5    Skanska         NA   60478.40         NA         NA   11523.06
6   Swedbank   49560.15         NA  161560.30  149519.25    8512.00
```

This is a much simpler command and gives a cleaner result.

Comment: Thank you very much! Works perfectly fine and much faster than a loop.

Comment: Should you have a large quantity of data, `data.table` handles it more efficiently. In that case try @Wimpel's answer

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution with the `tidyverse` package.
Note that no loops are needed here:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% as_tibble %>% group_by(Date, Company) %>% 
  summarise(x = mean(VolumeSEK)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  spread(Company, x)

# A tibble: 5 x 7
  Date       `Alfa Laval` Investor Kinnevik     SEB Skanska Swedbank
  <fct>             <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
1 11.09.2018       22246.   31687.  76522.  48348.      NA    49560.
2 12.09.2018       30550   119912.   9017.9 52926.   60478.      NA 
3 13.09.2018          NA       NA   29150    1254.0     NA   161560.
4 14.09.2018          NA    89315.  11943.     NA       NA   149519.
5 17.09.2018          NA       NA   65490.  35451.   11523.    8512
```